# Setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false creates multiple objects that instantly gets deinitialized

Tags: swift

This is my code:

```
import UIKit

class MyView: UIView {

    var nextView: NextView?

    private var button: UIButton! = UIButton()

    init(){
        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        commonLoad()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonLoad()
    }

    private func commonLoad() {
        addSubview(button)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false //comment this on and off to see the change
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        nextView = NextView(view: self)
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinit my view")
    }

}

class NextView {
    private weak var view: UIView?

    init(view: UIView){
        self.view = view
        guard let v = self.view else { fatalError() }
        let anotherSubView = UIView()
        v.addSubview(anotherSubView)
    }


    deinit {
        print("Deinit next view")
    }
}

class Test: UIViewController{

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: false) { (_) in
            let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
            let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "otherVC") as! otherVC
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = nextViewController
        }
    }

}
```

Notice the comment when changing the value of translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints from the buttn. Changing this value will get this weird behaviour.

This is my log after adding a MyView to the storyboard in class Test:

```
Deinit next view //<-- Instant called, WHY?!
deinit my view //<-- after 1 second, good
Deinit next view //<-- after 1 second, good, but why did it created another object of NextView?
```

When commenting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints off, the first printlog disappears. Why does changing the value of translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints instantly creates and nils the object NextView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, first of all you need to take a look at [translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622572-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco) documentation from Apple. It says:

> By default, the property is set to **true** for any view you programmatically create.

Now come to your example.

When you said ***commenting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints off***, it's ambiguous. You should either say comment/uncomment or use value of true/false. It would be easier to think.

Consider these two cases:

1. **`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true`**(by default, when creating from code), system assumes that you yourself are handling the framing of the view and propagates an extra pass to the `layoutSubviews()` in case you need to change the frame of any of your subviews.
2. **`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`**. System gets to know that your sub views will have frame calculated dynamically and for that reason you don't need any chance to re-frame your subviews. So the system doesn't propagate any extra pass to `layoutSubviews()`

Now you need to know when `deinit` gets called. For the simplest case, if any object is initialized the **second** time, the first object's `deinit` gets called. You should have get your answer by now.

Let me clear you up:

- When you used `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true` (or
  if you even didn't use) your `layoutSubviews()` is called twice. As a
  result you initialized `NextView` twice. When initializing the
  `NextView` second time, the first instance's `deinit` gets called.
- When you used `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`
  your `layoutSubviews()` is called once. Hence no `deinit` gets
  called.